# how to show line by line text in div in HTML

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have html page with text div i want that text should be display line by line when page is loaded.I have tried many tutorial but not getting how to do this

I have edited code now it work fine but it gets on all text one time in slide i want a break after every text of div.

```
               <div class="text_paragraph">
                <marquee direction="down" behavior="slide">

                <p>Bovine Respiratory Disease (BRD) is the leading cause of economic loss in the beef industry. <small>1, 2</small>
                    </p>
                 </marquee>
            </div>
            <div class="text_paragraph_1">
                <marquee direction="down" behavior="slide">

                <b>Economic loss:</b>
                <ul><li>Costs the industry an estimated $1 billion each year. <small>3, 4</small></li>
                    <li>Losses can be attributed to death, reduced feed and treatment costs.<small>3,4</small></li>
                    <li>Economic losses range from an estimated $57.48 to $239.69 per head. <small>1, 2</small></li>
                </ul>

            </marquee>        
            </div>
            <div class="text_paragraph_2">
                <marquee direction="down" behavior="slide">

                <b>Bacterial Culprits:</b>
                <p>Four bacterial pathogens are commonly associated with BRD. </p>
                <ul><li>Mannheimia haemolytica</li>
                    <li>Pasteurella multocida</li>
                    <li>Histophilus somni</li>
                    <li>Mycoplasma bovis </li></ul>
                    </marquee>

            </div>
```

Comment: Not enough information. You mean you don't want the text to show up all at once, but to appear slowly? Or do you mean you have plain text lines in the div that you want to display underneath one another instead of side by side with the returns ignored? Also, can you show what you have so far?

Comment: can we see some code? also, could you explain better what you are needing?

Comment: i mean as in powerpoint it shows first line then second then third line by in div

Comment: @ThOrndike i am adding the code of text div which i want to show

Comment: You'd need Javascript to do that. How much Javascript do you know? Or maybe CSS3 transitions could be used, but those are frustratingly counter-intuitive.

Comment: @Mr Lister I am new to CSS and Javascript i know just simple

Comment: @JacksonJ then this is where you should start: learn css and javascript. This is not possible with plain HTML.

Comment: @ThOrdike i have edited code of my text

Comment: @binarious yes i want to learn but can you help in related things for this

Comment: @JacksonJ try it for yourself first and when you have a specific problem where you're stuck, feel free to ask.

Comment: @binarious its ok but how to look for this is it transition in javascript or any thing else

Comment: If you don't want to learn Javascript, it _is_ possible to do it without... not without some severe compromises though. Be afraid. Be very afraid. http://jsfiddle.net/VKqtE/1/

Comment: @MrLister i have seen this but in this it zigzags can't it be smoth like last text

Comment: @MrLister see the edited code of mine

Answer (score 1):

using break tag ,because The break tag inserts a single line break.

```
   <br/>
```